# Firebase cloud messaging crashes when receiving notification

Tags: firebase, cloud, messaging

Hello there guys i have this problem today with fcm i was using it before works fine but now i am getting this errors

firebase cloud messaging, debuger https://dpaste.de/DpeH
MyFirebaseMessagingService java https://dpaste.de/hRVk

thanks for your help

Comment: can you show your dependency list from gradle?

Comment: hi there abdul thanks for your comment, here is my dependency gradle list
https://dpaste.de/F5Tz

Comment: Please try using the latest firebase library 10.0.0

Comment: Also please add null checks. Before using notification data, perform checks to see if they are null.

Answer (score 1):

When you received the data from the FCM for the notification, then you need to verify whether data is present or not. If you are directly accessing the object instead of checking whether the data is present or not then the App will crash.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check the data is available or not in the `onMessageReceived()`.

Answer (score 0):

you r reciving data is null or data is not there  so when notification ifs  atemping data as a sting there is null object so app crash